# How to download and run Wso2 API Manager for linux ubuntu?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I easily download binary wso2 api manger 3.2.0 and run it in windows. but for linux ubuntu it dose not work when run wso2server.sh

but when excute ./wso2server.sh , it throws following exception : `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wso2/wso2am-3.2.0/repository\conf\advanced\qpid-config.xml (No such file or directory`

what is wrong? and should I download installer for linux?
when download wso2am-linux-installer-x64-3.2.0.rpm and install it works.but  binary that I downloaded not work.

[image]

Comment: What `not work` means? What error do you get? Do you have JAVA_HOME  defined? What Java version?

Comment: yes I set JAVA_HOME and java version is 8. I Unzip the downloaded binary pack and execute ./wso2server.sh in Centos. could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to run APIM v320 in linux.

1. Go to https://wso2.com/api-management/previous-releases/ and download the APIM v320.
2. [image]
3. Make sure you download the pack specified in the binary section.
4. Unzip the downloaded pack.
5. Go to wso2am-3.2.0/bin
6. Execute ./wso2server.sh

Comment: Be aware, that downloading from *wso2.com*, you get: **FreeLicense for Non-commercial, Educational, or Trial use.** If you want OpenSource version on Apache license, you should download it from: https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/tag/v3.2.0 (Assets on bottom of page)

Comment: I did those steps, but when excute ./wso2server.sh , it throws  following exception :  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wso2/wso2am-3.2.0/repository\conf\advanced\qpid-config.xml (No such file    or directory)

Comment: @TohidMakari please add the last comment `FileNotFoundException: /opt/wso2/wso2am-3.2.0/repository\conf\advanced\qpid-config.xml ` to the main question, that's something useful

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to understand the problem. I unziped the wso2 in windows and then transfer to linux that caused this problem that should unzip into linux server.